# Permuations Generator

Tags: java, arrays, input, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I am trying to add the input of the user to my permutations list, but when I take the user input, the program just keeps running. I don't get any permutations when I hit enter after the third input. Here is my code:

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Scanner;

 /**
 This program demonstrates the permutation generator.
 */
 public class PermutationGeneratorDemo
 {
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Please enter a 4 letter word: ");
   String word1 = scan.next();
   System.out.println("Enter a 5 letter word: ");
   String word2 = scan.next();
   System.out.println("Enter a 6 letter word: ");
   String word3 = scan.next();


  PermutationGenerator generator = new PermutationGenerator(word1 + word2 + word3);
  ArrayList<String> permutations = generator.getPermutations();
  for (String s : permutations)
  {         
     System.out.println(s);
    }
   }
  }
```

Code for the permutations:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
This class generates permutations of a word.
*/
 public class PermutationGenerator
 {
  private String word;

 /**
  Constructs a permutation generator.
  @param aWord the word to permute
 */
 public PermutationGenerator(String aWord)
{
    word = aWord;
}

PermutationGenerator(String[] wordList) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

 /**
    Gets all permutations of a given word.
   */
 public ArrayList<String> getPermutations()
 {
  ArrayList<String> permutations = new ArrayList<String>();

  // The empty string has a single permutation: itself
  if (word.length() == 0) 
  { 
     permutations.add(word); 
     return permutations; 
  }

  // Loop through all character positions
  for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
  {
     // Form a simpler word by removing the ith character
     String shorterWord = word.substring(0, i)
           + word.substring(i + 1);

     // Generate all permutations of the simpler word
     PermutationGenerator shorterPermutationGenerator 
           = new PermutationGenerator(shorterWord);
     ArrayList<String> shorterWordPermutations 
           = shorterPermutationGenerator.getPermutations();

     // Add the removed character to the front of
     // each permutation of the simpler word, 
     for (String s : shorterWordPermutations)
     {
        permutations.add(word.charAt(i) + s);
     }
  }
  // Return all permutations
  return permutations;
 }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you included the code that actually generates the permutations...

Comment: @AmirAfghani is correct, just thought I'd add that: `Scanner#next` reads in the next `String` default-ly delimited by a `space`. `Scanner#nextLine` reads in the next line delimited by a `new-line` character.

Comment: The code for the permutations is now there too. I'm fairly new to Java. When I change the next() to nextLine(), I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: Your algorithm does not generate permutations.  Modify your program to accept 1 word and input "aaaa".  Look at what you get back....Consider using Guava's  Collections2.permutations method if this is not an academic exercise

Answer (score 4):

I thought the problem was infinite recursion earlier but after further inspection, your program does terminate properly. However you have to realize that it is factorial complexity to generate a list of permutations. 4+5+6 = 15. 15! is a very large number, 1.3076744e+12
from the Google calculator, that's why your program seems to never end.

Generating that many strings is going to take a while.

Try running the program with the inputs `a`, `b`, and `c` and you'll see that it works because it only needs to generate 3! = 6 strings.

Answer (score -1):

Scanner will always wait until an input will come. So you have to set a specific amount of values to read, or you have to mark the end of your input with a special character/string.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine()

Comment: That's what I thought at first however, his code is running into an infinite loop when it gets into his `getPermutations` method. I didn't down vote, not sure who did.

Comment: Obviously a user with no idea itself and the inability to discuss and solve problems in a team ;)